# Infopath form removing multiple spaces from url

Tags: infopath

I have a repeating section that displays an URL on an infopath form built from a list. Currently it displays URL with the spaces in it. I want to replace those spaces with a %20 to make them link correctly. I am currently using the below function to get it correct
  myURL = concat(substring-before(myURL, " "), "%20", substring-after(myURL, " ")) 
but  unfortunately this doesn't work for links with multiple spaces that need replaced.

e.g.

"http://google.com/ apples and oranges.aspx"

is changed to

"http://google.com/%20apples and oranges.aspx"

but i need it to be "https://google.com/%20apples%20and%20oranges.aspx."

Help me out in this .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got it other way.Since I am using a repeated table and the default hyperlink option given by the table I have deleted them and added the new hyperlink control and in data source i given the secondary data connection which I have created earlier to pull the urls. It brought all the urls as it is without any issues. Thanks.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Substring will just match on the first instance not find all occurrences. Try a translate function instead. `=translate(myURL, ' ', '%20');`

Comment: I have tried the translate function but not working as required. Any other catch? Thank you.